# How to listen to all ports (udp and tcp) or make them all appear open in Debian

Tags: firewall, tcp, udp

I got an external Debian server. The problem is that my university campus doesn't allow connections to go outside when the port is different than TCP port 22, 80, 443, or UDP port 123. I tested them manually. On my Debian server I would like to listen to all my UDP and TCP ports so I can clearly figure out which TCP and UDP ports my university let through their firewall. Nmap is wonderful on the client side to test that, but what should I do on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to listen to all ports.

Just use tcpdump:

```
tcpdump host <the-ip-address-your-scan-will-come-from>
```

Every packet that makes it through the firewall to the debian server will be shown.

Comment: Thank you for a lot for this. It solve the TCP port scanning. What about UDP?

Comment: ```tcpdump``` is a bit of a misnomer, it can capture any type of packet

Comment: `tcpdump -nnq src host <campus-ip> and not port ssh`